# Are CRLF lines ok in a Rails project deployed on Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, deployment, newline

I have a Git repository (originally CVS, then SVN, now Git) containing a Rails project that has been deployed on Linux for a while now.  Everything seems to run fine.

Now that I've converted to git, I see that **many of my files in the repository contain [`CRLF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) line endings**.  I'd love for it to all be consistent (`LF`), but not at the expense of loosing the edit history of every file that has `CRLF` line endings.

**Can you think of any reason I can't leave the files as they are?**  I seem to remember there being a problem with shell scripts or cron files or something that didn't respond to `CRLF` very well.

Also, I know all about the Git options `core.autocrlf` and `core.safecrlf`, But is there some way to have it **convert all text files from `CRLF` to `LF` on checkout (for the linux side)** ... i.e. a core.autolf option or something similar?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "loosing [sic] the edit history of every file that has CRLF line endings." How would adding a commit which makes the line endings consistent cause you to "lose  the edit history?"

Comment: Some version control systems (i.e., Subversion) look at a file that has had it's line endings changed and think every line in the file has changed.

Comment: Such as subversion AND Git.  Seems Git uses only LF internally, so CR is just part of the text, if it changes, the line is changed.  I wouldn't loose the edit history, but diffing a file across that line-changing-commit would show the whole file as being changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is ok for you to rewrite your repository's history (see [problems with rewriting history](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#problems-With-rewriting-history)) you could use git filter-branch to convert CRLF to LF:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -path './.git' -prune -o -type f -exec dos2unix \{} \;' HEAD
```

Note that if you have binary files in your repository you will have to refine the find command to exclude them.

Comment: Just tried it with dos2unix from Ubuntu's tofrodos package (version 1.7.6-2) and it does not leave binary files alone. So the find command should be refined to exclude binary files if you have any in your repository.

Comment: Yeah, this would work if I can only find a good way to make sure and leave binary files alone.

Comment: It looks like, at least with dos2unix 6, dos2unix will skip binary files, so this should work.

Answer (score 1):

A [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/how-do-i-add-a-comment-to-an-answer) to davitenio's answer and Daniel Beardsley's comment; I believe you could use this little program as a wrapper around dos2unix:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $@; do
    if [ $(file -b -n -i -m /dev/null $f | grep -c "text") -gt 0 ]; then
        dos2unix $f
    fi
done
```

although there is probably still some corner case that will fail.