# Merge files with different end-of-line character

Tags: git, diff, git-merge, end-of-line

I work with GIT on Linux, and my colleague works with GIT on Windows.

I commited some changes to a file, and my colleague commited some other changes to that file.

My colleague pushed, and I pulled.

Now, my entire file is a one big conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
...
[my version]
....
=======
...
[colleague's version]
...
>>>>>>> branch 'master' of https://github.com/rothariel/aimnegochat.git
```

What can I do? How can I merge the changes?

Comment: if you need the line endings of a single file coming in (which is possibly the reverse of the situation described in this question) you could also try what I've just done - before merging, set the line endings to the desired value, then commit that and retry the pull/merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this article in github you can overcome such problem

the suggested eol is \n, you can use this to autoconvert

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
# Set this setting on OSX or Linux

git config --global core.autocrlf true
# Set this setting on Windows
```

Have a look at the example what to do next.

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question of "what do I do now?"  This answers the question "How do I avoid this in the future."  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522933/clarifying-clearing-up-line-ending-issues-in-git for getting yourself out of the current mess, then get your windows friends follow this answer for the future.

Comment: You are right, I need a solution for now. The first link you mentioned explains how to do the merge, the problem is I already did the merge... The second link explains how to fix the repository, but not how to rescue the merged file...

Comment: Rescue the merged files ? git checkout to a previous state then perform the merge after you have set the right configurations as in the github article.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

```
git merge <master|branch|whatever> -s recursive -Xignore-space-at-eol
```

Seems to do what I need it to do, but it gave me errors:

```
error: addinfo_cache failed for path ...
```

However:

```
git merge <master|branch|whatever> -s recursive -X renormalize
```

Seems to do the trick.

I've still got issues with line endings every time i check in files. Something in the commit / merge process is switching my line endings back to what they shouldn't be.

I've tried messing around with the

```
git config --global core.autocrlf <true|input|false>
```

settings, but it doesn't seem to resolve the fact that something is changing my line endings in the git tool chain.

Answer (score -1):

You need to merge the changes your colleague has done with your changes. Simply edit the file and `add to index`. You can `commit` your changes after that.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I asked... How can I merge the changes? I don't even know what was the colleague's changes nor remember my changes... Usually the merge happens automatically, is there a way to make that happen in this case?

Comment: You don't need to remember your changes or your colleagues changes. `<<<<<< HEAD` and `>>>>>> master` shows which particular area is different between your local and remote branch. You can simply lookup each sentence which are different. Please also take a look at `git mergetool` command.

Comment: The problem is, my entire file is surrounded by these tags (i.e. all my version of the file, from beginning to end, is betweeh the "HEAD" and the "=====", while all my colleague's version of the file, from beginning to end, is between the "=====" and end-of-file. This is because of the end-of-line difference between Linux and Windows.

Comment: abort the merge, "edit the file" > set the line endings to the desired value, then re-pull the changes. you may need to use a different `diff` tool if you've already "accepted the merge" (ie saved the conflicted state) - in which case I'd use the version of the file _before_ the conflict was saved, change the line endings, then try and merge in the `origin` version of the main branch to that