# With Git, how do I turn off the "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warning

Tags: git, line-endings, git-config

With Git, when using the `autocrlf = true` flag, a warning is still given when line-endings are changed.

I understand what the warning is for, and how to turn off the line-ending flag, but how do I turn off the warning itself?

Comment: All the answers here are obsolete — after git introduced gitattributes. Safecrlf is your friend autocrlf is not!  Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414)

Answer (score 366):

You can turn off the warning with

```
git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

(This will only turn off the warning, not the function itself.)

Comment: will turning off the warning prevent git from replacing lf by crlf? @chronial

Comment: @aidonsnous From [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/1.7.3.3): If core.safecrlf is set to "true" or "warn", git verifies if the conversion is reversible for the current setting of core.autocrlf. For "true", git rejects irreversible conversions; for "warn", git only prints a warning but accepts an irreversible conversion. If you do not need to reject irreversible conversions, setting core.safecrlf to false suppresses the warning, but still auto converts.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `core.autocrlf input` and `core.eol input`. Or just don't let git change the line endings at all with `autocrlf false` and get rid of highlighting of crlfs in diffs, etc with `core.whitespace cr-at-eol`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Usually, you want that your BAT scripts ends and be commited with CRLF, and your SH script with LF.

Answer (score 4):

I used this way:

> Save your current files in Git, so that none of your work is lost.
>
> ```
> git add . -u
> git commit -m "Saving files before refreshing line endings"
> ```
>
> Remove every file from Git's index.
>
> ```
> git rm --cached -r .
> ```
>
> Rewrite the Git index to pick up all the new line endings.
>
> ```
> git reset --hard
> ```
>
> Add all your changed files back, and prepare them for a commit. This
>   is your chance to inspect which files, if any, were unchanged.
>
> ```
> git add .
> # It is perfectly safe to see a lot of messages here that read
> # "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."
> ```
>
> Commit the changes to your repository.
>
> ```
> git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
> ```

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: I believe the OP was trying to avoid seeing those warnings anymore. Not normalize all of the line endings.

Comment: `git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard` seems to do the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `core.whitespace` option (see `git config --help` for details).

You can set this option like so:

```
$ git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I had applied both configs like explained here, and my .gitconfig file contained these 2 lines:

```
[core]
       autocrlf = false
       whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

Yet I got the warning.
Now just to try I commented out both lines and the warning actually disappeared.
No idea why I put them in the first place however...

Comment: Did you have different settings for your repository?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...
I don't have my config file anymore but I use a similar one I think now and apart from these 2 lines, there's nothing related.

Comment: Because if there are other settings in yout `.git/config` that would override your global ones

Answer (score 0):

Setting "core.safecrlf false" works. However, after I changed the value to 'true' The output changes from 'warning' to 'fatal' as shown below.

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

$ git config --global core.safecrlf false

$ git reset

$ git config --global core.safecrlf true

$ git add -A
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore

$
```

Comment: In recent git better to use gitattributes than autocrlf. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644154/3700414). All answers (on this q) are old and obsolete