# Can I suppress the messages that "LF will be replaced by CRLF"?

Tags: git, git-bash

Can I suppress such messages in the console of Git Bash (the output of the `git commit` command)?

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in 1.txt.
>  The file will have its
>   original line endings in your working directory.

The `--quiet` option doesn't do it.

Comment: **See Also**: [With Git, how do I turn off the "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500880/1366033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the `safecrlf` configuration:

```
git config core.safecrlf false
```

> ### `core.safecrlf`
>
> If true, makes Git check if converting `CRLF` is reversible when
>   end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if a command
>   modifies a file in the work tree either directly or indirectly. For
>   example, committing a file followed by checking out the same file
>   should yield the original file in the work tree. If this is not the
>   case for the current setting of `core.autocrlf`, Git will reject the
>   file. The variable can be set to "warn", in which case Git will only
>   warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the operation.