# core.autocrlf not fixing CRLF would be replaced by LF

Tags: git, github

I'm running into the same problem as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important) but the solution, to change `core.autocrlf`, isn't working on my mac 10.6.8:

```
$ git config core.autocrlf false
$ git add .
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/.gitattributes.
$ git config core.autocrlf true
$ git add .
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
```

If I delete the bootstrap file the error will just flag a different file

Answer (score 1):

something to do with my package.json and node_modules including jade by itself, deleted those files and I'm good to go