# Problem when creating a new angular project in cli using npm on windows

Tags: angular, git, npm, command-line-interface

So i'm following a udemy angular course and the instructor is using mac while i'm using windows. When I create a new project I get different screen from him is that normal or am I missing something. The screens are attached , mine is the black screen .[I get a series of create commands followed by a series of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnK1R.png)

[its followed by a successfully initialized git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUBfE.png)

[he gets a series of create also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjFlU.jpg)

[But is followed by series of installs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0S6D.jpg)

```
    A:\Work\Projects> ng new first-website
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE first-website/angular.json (3622 bytes)
CREATE first-website/package.json (1289 bytes)
CREATE first-website/README.md (1029 bytes)
CREATE first-website/tsconfig.json (489 bytes)
CREATE first-website/tslint.json (3125 bytes)
CREATE first-website/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE first-website/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE first-website/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE first-website/karma.conf.js (1025 bytes)
CREATE first-website/tsconfig.app.json (210 bytes)
CREATE first-website/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/index.html (298 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/polyfills.ts (2835 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/app/app.component.html (25725 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (963 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/app/app.component.ts (217 bytes)
CREATE first-website/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE first-website/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE first-website/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE first-website/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (646 bytes)
CREATE first-website/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
√ Packages installed successfully.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .editorconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in angular.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in browserslist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/protractor.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.po.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/tsconfig.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in karma.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.module.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.prod.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/polyfills.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/styles.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/test.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.app.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.spec.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tslint.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
    Successfully initialized git.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a standard on Windows to use two bytes for line return.

It just means that file created will be modified to better fit the standards of the operating system your are using.

Nothing much to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can disregard these warnings. As far as I remember they are related to git. When I took his Angular course a few months ago I didn't have any issues using Win 10 Pro.

Are you using vs code terminal for your cli/npm installs?

Here is the information from his course content 1.5 on troubleshooting the instalations:

> A lot of problems are solved by making sure you're using the latest
>   version of NodeJS, npm and the CLI itself.
>
> Updating NodeJS:
>
> Go to nodejs.org and download the latest version - uninstall (all)
>   installed versions on your machine first.
>
> Updating npm:
>
> Run [sudo] `npm install -g npm`  (sudo  is only required on Mac/ Linux)
>
> Updating the CLI
>
> [sudo] `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` @angular/cli
>
> npm cache verify
>
> [sudo] `npm install -g` @angular/cli
>
> Here are some common issues & solutions:
>
> Creation of a new project takes forever (longer than 3 minutes) That
>   happens on Windows from time to time => Try running the command line
>   as administrator
>
> You get an EADDR error (Address already in use) You might already have
>   another ng serve process running - make sure to quit that or use ng
>   serve --port ANOTHERPORT  to serve your project on a new port
>
> My changes are not reflected in the browser (App is not compiling)
>   Check if the window running ng serve  displays an error. If that's not
>   the case, make sure you're using the latest CLI version and try
>   restarting your CLI

Hope it helps

Comment: so should I ignore this warnings and start working on the project or something is missing?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Concerning this specific warning you can answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important).

But if I would summarize it in a few words - ignore and keep working on your app if you are doing a project for yourself not for a general public.

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark my answer correct if you think that it answered your question. Cheers

Comment: even the lts version have same problem, so i will disregard this worning..  thanks