# Gitignor Unity Renaming Blank and Not Working after push and pull

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

I'm trying to set up a team with GitHub but whenever someone pulls files onto their computer the .gitignore file renames itself to blank and does not seem to be working.  I still get the "The file will have its original line endings in your working directory. warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile." errors along with more LF to be replaced with CRLF errors

I've tried putting in many different .gitignore variations for unity files and placed the file in many folders at different levels. None of this is working. The person who pulled the git file cannot push it back because they get "CRLF to LF" errors. What am i doing wrong!?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhPz1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLRF to LF warning is just that, a warning and it will not prevent you from pushing back to a repo. You can learn more about line endings and how to handle robustly or ignore the warning here:

[LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)