# while i am adding files in git , i am getting this LF warning , is it something that i need to be worried about?

Tags: git

while i am adding files in git , i am getting this warning, is it something that i need to be worried about ?

$ git add --all

warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flask-marshmallow/app.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flask-marshmallow/models/item.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flask-marshmallow/models/store.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in flask-marshmallow/resources/store.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)