# Stuck on git add

Tags: git, github

My git seems to be stuck. I was trying to start pushing my project onto GitHub.

I have done the following:

`git init`

`git add .`

When doing `git add .` I was getting a non stop message running saying:

`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF.`  for all my files.

I saw an article online that said to do, which I did :

`git config ---global core.autocrlf false`

I then tried to do `git add .` again and it is completely stuck.

Upon doing `git status` I get a number of untracked files.

Any idea of what this error is?

Comment: `LF will be replaced by CRLF` il probably caused by how your OS manage ending line (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important))

Comment: [`git add ---renormalize`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---renormalize)

Comment: thanks @Berto99 changing ```git config -- global``` mentioned to ```true``` sorted it my problem.