# Error message when opening Angular project

Tags: angular, command-line

When I create a new Angular project through a command line, the project is successfully created but then the following message appears, is this OK? I will note that the project is running normally and everything is working but this message appears.

Many thanks to the helpers.

> √ Packages installed successfully.
>
> warning: LF will be replaced by
> CRLF in .browserslistrc. The file will have its original line endings
> in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> .editorconfig. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md. The file will have
> its original line endings in your working directory warning: LF will
> be replaced by CRLF in angular.json. The file will have its original
> line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by
> CRLF in e2e/protractor.conf.js. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in e2e/src/app.po.ts. The file will have its original line endings in
> your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> e2e/tsconfig.json. The file will have its original line endings in
> your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> karma.conf.js. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> package-lock.json. The file will have its original line endings in
> your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> package.json. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> src/app/app-routing.module.ts. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in src/app/app.component.html. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in src/app/app.component.spec.ts. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in src/app/app.component.ts. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in src/app/app.module.ts. The file will have its original line endings
> in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> src/environments/environment.prod.ts. The file will have its original
> line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by
> CRLF in src/environments/environment.ts. The file will have its
> original line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be
> replaced by CRLF in src/index.html. The file will have its original
> line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by
> CRLF in src/main.ts. The file will have its original line endings in
> your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> src/polyfills.ts. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
> src/styles.css. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/test.ts.
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.app.json. The file
> will have its original line endings in your working directory warning:
> LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.base.json. The file will have
> its original line endings in your working directory warning: LF will
> be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.json. The file will have its original
> line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by
> CRLF in tsconfig.spec.json. The file will have its original line
> endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
> in tslint.json. The file will have its original line endings in your
> working directory
> Successfully initialized git.

Picture of the message error :

[image]

Comment: Check this question [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignorate it I supose. You're getting a project made in a different operational system, eg: Unix and Windows, that respectively use LF and CRLF in the end of its files' line.

By your image we can see that you are using Windows because it convert LF (Unix) to CRLF (Windows). You can skip it using a **git** configuration:

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

Or in Angular with TSLint **linebreak-style** setting:

```
"linebreak-style": [true, "CRLF"]
```

As explained at https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/linebreak-style/