# Warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF issue on Ubuntu

Tags: git, tableau-api

Recently I have started using the tableau dashboard. I have downloaded the Tableau workbook (.twbx) first from the tableau interface and then written a script which helps to publish the dashboard through API.

So whenever I'm going to push this unzipped workbook folder through git on the Unix system.
It throws the below warning

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in scripts/tableau/Fit.twbx.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in scripts/tableau/Fit/Data/Extracts/federated_0su8t1k1es5468150761q0.hyper.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in scripts/tableau/Fit/Fit.twb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

I have also tried the below options to get out of this situation.

1. `git config --global core.autocrlf input`
2. added this in `.gitattributes` file: `*.twb eol=crlf`, `*.hyper eol=crlf`

The above options are not worked for me to prevent the warning.

Because of this, whenever I'm going to publish the dashboard through the API, it's throwing the below error while publishing the dashboard on the server.

```
"error": "unable to drop database \"hyper.file:Fitda43d2e571dd4ae982a54915b1408e0c/Data/Extracts/federated_0su8t1k1es5468150761q0.hyper\": file is truncated: expected file size 262144, actual file size 262142\nContext: 0x5fdfad59
```

Due to this byte loss, I'm unable to publish the dashboard on the server.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Note: It works fine when I put the unzipped folder directly on the server.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834094/5784831 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/5784831

Comment: This is just a recommendation, not a requirement, and not an answer to your problem either, but: never use `core.autocrlf` (always leave it completely unset). The `eol=` settings are OK to use sometimes (but quite likely not a solution to this problem either).

Comment: Now, a question for you to answer: these three files you name, whose endings are `.twbx`, `.twb`, and `.hyper`: are they plain-text files, or are they binary files? What software actually *reads* these files?

Comment: @torek- they are binary files, we're modifying the content in between and then re-generating the .hyper file using tableau hyper engine

Comment: @Christoph- already tried but didn't work in my case