# while commiting changes from github desktop, I get an error saying "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in author/test/index.html"

Tags: git, github-desktop

[ScreenShot Attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkLrv.png)   I am building static webpage though wordpress/simply static but while commiting changes from github desktop, I get an error saying "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in 2021/09/25/hello-world/feed/index.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory" for almost all files. I I did some reading on line endings, and tried some git commands suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important) using Repository > Open Repository in Command Prompt, no luck.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.