# git add giving a super long never ending output

Tags: bash, git, github, git-add

So I am kinda new to git and github and wanted to push a project on github. However, when I add files

```
git add .
```

it gives a super long message that does not seem to end

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Lib/site-packages/Django-3.0.3.dist-info/AUTHORS.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Lib/site-packages/Django-3.0.3.dist-info/INSTALLER.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Lib/site-packages/Django-3.0.3.dist-info/LICENSE.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Lib/site-packages/Django-3.0.3.dist-info/LICENSE.python.
```

This keeps going on, where am I wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-add%5D+warning%3A+LF+will+be+replaced+by+CRLF

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/Unix machines the end of a line is represented by a *LF*. On Windows machines, a line is represented by a *CR* and a *LF*; *CRLF*. when you get code from git installed from a Linux/Unix system they will only have one *LF*. If you don't care that git automatically replaces LFs with CRLFs, you can turn off this warning by typing the following on the git command line:

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

---

###### Abbreviations

- `LF`: *Line Feed*
- `CR`: *Carriage Return*
- `CRLF`: *Carriage Return Line Feed*

---

###### References

- [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important)