# Prettier on git commit hook shows code style issues, but only CRLF differences

Tags: javascript, bash, git, prettier

I'm using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) In my TypeScript project. I format all files on save in Visual Studio Code.
I also configured a [pre-commit git hook with Husky](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html#option-4-huskynethttpsgithubcomalirezanethuskynet) which checks the formatting of all files.

This is how my `pre-commit` hook file looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd ./MyApp/ClientApp

npx prettier --check .
```

Now comes the fun part. I work with files in `MyApp/ClientApp` directory with VS Code, which does all the formatting on save. So far so good.

However, when I'm trying to make a commit, Prettier pre-commit hook gets executed and I get the following error:

```
git commit
Checking formatting...
[warn] src\dataTypes\numeratorObjectType.ts
[warn] src\viewModels\numeratorViewModel.ts
[warn] Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

If I open these files in VS Code and save them, nothing happens as they have already been formatted.

So I execute Prettier manually by running the following command in `MyApp/ClientApp` directory:

```sh
npx prettier --write .
```

This command outputs all the files, with the two problematic ones apparently reformatted:

[image]

I also see these files changed in git. However, `git diff` shows nothing. When I execute `git add .`, I'm getting the following warning:

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory. warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF
```

Which means these files only had issues with line endings.
According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important), I set the following config parameters in my git repository:

```sh
git config core.autocrlf true
git config core.safecrlf false
```

It seems to make the warning with CRLF disappear when doing `git add`, but it still doesn't solve the issue with Prettier. It still shows code style issues, even though there are no real differences/styling issues in the files.

I'm on Windows, as that might be important I guess.

Any idea what can be wrong here? Currently, checking Prettier formatting on pre-commit hook makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have **multiple formatters** installed? For example the *beautify* plugin in VS Code? Because it might interfere with prettier. 
Otherwise try running `yarn prettier path/to/file.js` to check the output of the prettier.

Comment: It seems likely that the code formatter you ran switched the line endings from LF-only to CRLF or vice versa. Because you're *also* having *Git* switch line endings, the two programs are competing for how the files are stored in your working tree. But Git doesn't *use* the working tree copy, except to produce the index copy when running `git add`; Git produces the index copy during `git add` by doing the line-ending editing that you called for. The working tree copy is not changed in the process, but Git warns you that a future `git checkout` would be different.

Comment: In particular, your working tree files are *yours* to do with as you will, but when you use `git checkout` or `git switch`, you're asking that *Git* should *replace* your existing working tree files with those from the commit you have asked Git to check out. If you're also having Git do line-ending mucking-about, that might mean *replace LF-only line endings as stored in the repository with CRLF line endings in my working tree copy*. If your prettifier *took out* CRLFs, this puts them back (later, not now!).

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems I found a solution, assuming all developers are on Windows. I configured git with `git config core.autocrlf false` (so it doesn't do the CRLF -> LF conversion). I also set `endOfLine` to `crlf` in Prettier's configuration file. For now it seems all is good. I will test it more and post an an answer here if it works ;) The only annoying thing is that now git adds `^M` character in the end of every line, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging the issue more and thanks to comments from **@eDonkey** and **@torek**, I found a solution. I tested it for 2 days and it seems to work.

Please note, that this solution probably works for a project with Windows-only developers. If all of you are on Mac/Linux, you'd probably want to use LF instead of CRLF. If the team is mixed, I'm not sure there's a perfect solution here.

First, configure `git` to not do CRLF -> LF conversion:

```sh
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Next, configure Prettier to use CRLF as the end of line character. You can do it by adding the following setting into [Prettier's config file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html):

```json
"endOfLine": "crlf"
```

If some of your files have already had the LF line endings, you might need to convert them to CRLF. It's enough to use `npx prettier --write .` for that.

The only thing I noticed is that `git` now adds `^M` character at the end of each line:

[image]

But it's not an issue for me.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding `"endOfLine": "auto"` to my `.prettierrc` file.