# How to fix Git warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF

Tags: git, github

I need help with an error when pushing to github

1. What is causing the Git warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF error?
2. How to fix Git warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF

   ```
    cd "C:\Users\JMLEE\Desktop\파이썬\hw6"
    Git init
    git remote add origin https://github.com/rlaalswo1222/hw6.git
    git add .
    git status
    git commit -m "hw"
    git push origin master
   ```

Answer (score 13):

It's not an error. It's telling you an action it will do to keep the standards

> What is causing the Git warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF error?

It's the "end of the line" representation. This can be editted in most of editors (i.e. VSCode).

[image: VSCode CRLF]

What it says is that when ending a line, this ending representation will be a CRLF character. CRLF means *Carriage Return and Line Feed*. For more info on this, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).

> How to fix Git warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF

To "fix" this, you just need to set a standard. If you want CRLF as standard (the "Windows default"), you just need to make your editors use CRLF. And vice-versa. **It's not a problem though**, it just converts the EOL's to the standard. You can also disable this option. [There's a good answer to how to setup git for those configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821931/10473393)

On VSCode, taking as example, there's a good extension to see those end-of-lines https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=medo64.render-crlf
Most edittors can also show those characters somehow, but it isn't enabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

This command will help to fix that warning

```
     git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That configuration wouldn't "help" to fix the warning, because that configuration is *causing* the warning. That is not the only configuration that could cause the warning, however. A `.gitattributes` file where the `text` attribute is set for files would cause this warning, too, if the `eol` attribute for those files was not set to `lf`.

Comment: This command by itself doesn't seem to fix the warning. You might need to refresh the repository after changing the line endinds says [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings?platform=windows#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings)

Comment: After following the [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings?platform=windows#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings) you will also need to run `git config --global core.safecrlf false` to remove the warning safely says [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834094/9049673)