# error: open("projectName/Temp/UnityLockfile"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path projectName/Temp/UnityLockfile

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

So before this I had a problem which is: [LF will be replaced by CRLF in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important), At the end I managed to disable the warning messages by typing in the command prompt the following:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

And the warning disappeared and I went to my GitHub desktop and commit it, Everything was working fine till this error popped up `error: open("projectName/Temp/UnityLockfile"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path projectName/Temp/UnityLockfile`.

I'm in windows 10, Making a unity project.

Comment: There are many files in Unity projects that should not be committed to source control including all of `Temp/*`. You need a `.gitignore` file. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore should get you started.

Comment: @RetiredNinja hey i still did what you've told me and the same error keeps popping

Comment: It's possible you put the file in the wrong place, named it incorrectly, or if you've already staged files you'll need to unstage them and then stage them again.

Comment: If you had added `UnityLockfile` (or any other file under `Temp/`) in a previous commit, you need one extra command to make git "forget" about it : see  ["How can I make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057)

Answer (score 1):

Close Unity and try again. It works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35727517)