# does a git repository have its own local value for core.autocrlf that overrides the global one?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf), I understand that core.autocrlf=true in git will cause CRLF to LF translations.

However when I type :
     git config core.autocrlf

I see:
     false

However, when I stage modified files that are already in the repo, I still get these warnings:

```
Warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in File1.X.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

My guess is that the repo copy of the file is already set to "autocrlf=true".

Questions: A. How do I query whether a file or git repo is already forcing AutoCrlf?
B. How do I turn it autocrlf off?

Comment: I would like to know if you can have a "local" copy of the .gitattributes file that you DON'T check into source control?  I'd like to have some repos be "windows style" settings and only 1 repo to be LINUX style, without forcing all users of that repo to use LINUX.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you put in a git global setting that only applies locally to a particular directory (i.e. REPO)?  I want some repos to be WINDOWS and some to be LINUX style line endings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git allows you to override your global setting on a per-repository basis with a .gitattributes file. You put it in the root directory of the repository, and becomes a file committed as part of the repository. I suspect this is happening in your case.

Github has a good page on this: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

In short, you can use the text attribute to set the line endings for a particular file extension. For instance, forcing sln files to CRLF would require the following line in a .gitattributes file :

```
# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf
```

Comment: Right... so... what would I put in `.gitattributes` that would be the equivalent of `core.autocrlf=false` in my global config?

Comment: So would the following in `.gitattributes` be equivalent to `core.autocrlf=false`? `* -text`

Comment: No. .gitattributes also affects ability to merge if you remove binary.

Comment: This answer did not actually answer the specific question asked, so it should not have been marked as the answer.  I came here looking for an answer to the exact same question:  how do I simply set `core.autocrlf=false` per-repo?  I don't want to have to explicitly list out specific EOL types to use for specific files or file extensions.  I just want the entire Git repo to always be shown to all developers of it _verbatim_, without mangling EOLs in any file type, ever.