# I got one error when i'am try to make a new file in master directory

Tags: git, github, git-branch

When i try to make a file in master directory using git bash, i got one Error Message something like: "LF will be replaced by CRLF in plan(plan is the name of my new file which i try to create.)."

Is there anyone who could help me to find out the solution regarding this problem?

Comment: How do you create the file ? With *touch* ?

Comment: first i create new branch name as first"git checkout -b first"  then i add plan file by using the following command 1."echo My system first > plan" 2."git add plan" then i got this type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to avoid this problem is to run `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

If you want to learn more about the issue, please go through [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/20653073#20653073)