# What is going wrong in my git svn workflow?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

Since I prefer git over svn I've tried to clone the svn repository of my company and work on it over git svn. So far this works fine. I can receive svn updates and commit my changes as usual.

However I'm having serious issues when changes overlap. I.e. I've been working on a feature which is not fully completed yet, so I have committed one part of it into my private git working copy but now can't go for a SVN rebase to update and merge my version with the svn head. When I try to do so, it tells me that my working copy isn't clean and that I need to stash my changes. Then svn fetch is running and a window pops up (I'm using TortoiseGit) where I can configure the rebase process. I select the master branch at the state of my partial feature and remotes/git-svn as upstream. Clicking 'start rebase' it again asks me to stash my changes twice in a row which is already very strange. Doing so it outputs an error message: 'your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: my_modified_partial_features_files.foo'. Why is this a problem? I thought that's why I stashed before? If I then abort the rebase, it asks me to stash pop and again fails, telling me the merge would fail for all files now changed in the last svn commit.

Where is my mistake? Right now I can't get even push my changes into the svn repository because I have to update and merge first. So basically I can't get back and forth at all.

Comment: Can you see whether you would get issues from command line? (git bash I assume?). Looks more like TortoiseGit issue to me, on the first sight.

Comment: I will try to stick to the command line in the future however right now I have another problem that doesn't really make any sense. I've tried to start from the beginning and cloned the svn repository into a frech git one again. Now it shows me a empty diffs for a whole bunch of files even though I haven't changed anything (and this has worked before!). Reverting or resetting doesn't help either, all files stay modified. I'm starting to think, I should look for a different solution than working with git svn.

Comment: sounds like [cr-lf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: I thought that too but I can decide whether I want to commit my changes in linux or windows endings when cloning for the first time. And it didn't apply to all but just a bunch of source files. In the meantime I've cloned once again and the problem is gone - really weird.