# How to avoid "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in"?

Tags: windows, git, configuration, eol

I'm on Windows 8.1. The complete message is:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file1.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

I get that message after:

1- `mkdir testing; cd testing; git init`

2- `notepad++ file1` (I added text in *file1* using Unix EOL configuration of notepad++, so LF is being using. I even tested that opening the file in `notepad`)

3- `git add .` and bum! I get the message.

My configuration is:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    eol = lf
```

Why the message when I have **eol as lf** and my file just have LF as end of line?

My goal is work with LF on the repo and on any file in my working directory without that annoying message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)