# Push yeoman project to github

Tags: github, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I try to work on a yeoman project with a team. After generating the angularjs code with  > yo angular and pushed the folder to github

```
git add .
git push
git commit origin master
```

and when I clone the code from git github I have this error

> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or
>   grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more
>   information about installing and configuring grunt, please see the
>   Getting Started guide:
>
> http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

so I deleted every thing from .gitignore and pushed everything again, I had this warning

> The file will have its original line endings in your working
>   directory.

So I am quite sure it's not going to work and it's not the best way to do it. Can someone help me on how to upload the yeoman project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that angular generator for Yeoman already creates a package.json file with grunt defined as dependency along with all its task. So the correct way to compile a project after the clone is to install all npm dependencies locally using:

```
npm install
```

then run grunt to compile everything:

```
grunt
```

Of course you must have grunt-cli globally installed, which is used to run grunt locally. To install it you have to use the following command where **-g** defined the global install (default is local):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: also run bower install after npm install

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i think you have a typo in your question, you have mixed `commit` and `push` commands:

```
 git add .
 git commit -m 'commit message' // message is optional
 git push origin master
```

First message appears because you don't have an installed Grunt. [Install](http://gruntjs.com/installing-grunt) it in your working directory:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

> Starting with Grunt v0.4, you should never install Grunt itself
>   globally. For more information about why, please read [this](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation). Source: [grunt-cli docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli).

If it is alredy listed in the devDependencies, just run:

```
npm install
```

The second one is caused by line-endings. It is a good practice to include `.gitattributes` file in your repo. File's content should be:

```
* text=auto
```

Read about this file: [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). Or there is another method. It is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf).

Comment: And as @Alerosa mentioned, it is a handy to install grunt-cli.