# Git Bash Warning for ipynb(jupyter notebook)

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, git-bash

I get this warning while adding the jupyter notebook file in Git:

$ git add project.ipynb
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Downloads/project.ipynb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

[Help on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523236/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-the-file-will-have-its-original-line-endings/48111017?noredirect=1#comment83197528_48111017)

If my file is ".ipynb" that is a jupyter notebook then what should I do in that case? I am new to Git and Github, can anyone please answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: It should not matter, the notebook are JSON so lf/crlf should have no effect.

Comment: Thanks Matt. When I made a commit and push for the same file it was uploaded into the remote repository but I can't see the changes on the webpage where this jupyter notebook is supposed to be seen. Can you please tell me the reason behind it? I did it by making a clone of the remote repository, then modified the jupyter notebook, then added to git, then commit, and pushed.