# Git-SVN can't reset my repo

Tags: git, svn

I was configuring my Git-SVN repo (filter, .gitignore, etc.) when all the sudden it started to have strange behaviors.

My problem at the moment is that I can't reset my repo.
I tried:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at a5e6951 My comment
```

From my understanding, I shouldn't have any file modified in my working copy anymore.
But it is not the case:

```
$ git st
On branch dev
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Main.c
        [...]
```

I have plenty of others strange behaviors (.gitignore doesn't work, etc.).

My question:

- What is happening?
- How can I properly reset my environment?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here someday, I finally noticed it is an EOL issue (CRLF vs LF).
Fixing this is a pain.
I recommend reading this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/882697