# What is the difference between eol=lf and text in a .gitattributes file?

Tags: git

According to [the documentation on .gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), `text` enables end-of-line normalization:

> `text`
>
> Setting the text attribute on a path enables end-of-line normalization and marks the path as a text file. End-of-line conversion takes place without guessing the content type.

According to the same documentation, `eol=lf` will also normalize linebreaks:

> `eol`
>
> This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the working 
>   directory. It enables end-of-line normalization without any content checks, 
>   effectively setting the text attribute.

The fact that the examples given mix them in the same file seems to imply that there is some (perhaps subtle) difference between them:

```
*.txt       text
*.vcproj    eol=crlf
*.sh        eol=lf
*.jpg       -text
```

Also, there seems to nowhere be an unambiguous statement that they are the same, or that `text` is shorthand for `eol=lf`—though that *appears* to be the case.  The closest thing I could find to such a statement is what I quoted above, where it says "effectively setting the text attribute".  But the word *effectively* seems to back-pedal just slightly, as though it's not *actually* setting the text attribute, but just *more-or-less* setting it, or having almost the same effect.

What, *precisely*, is the difference between these two?  (Or is `text` just shorthand for the common use case?)  Is there any reason you would mix the two in one `.gitattributes` file?

OR: does `text` require that Git guess which kind of linebreak you need, while `eol` (obviously) specifies?

Comment: I think `eol=lf` explicitly prevents conversion to CRLF when a file is checked out, whereas `text` _might_ introduce CRLF depending on the system Git configuration.

Comment: AFAIK from [here](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/), the system Git config only applies if your file type is unspecified: "If a file is unspecified then Git falls back to the core.autocrlf setting and you are back in the old system."

Answer (score 7):

`eol` tells Git which line endings to use in your *working directory* and **also** enables LF normalization for those files in the *repository*. This setting applies to a particular path, so I'll use `*.txt` in my examples:

- `*.txt eol=crlf` tells Git to (1) normalize line endings to LF on checkin and (2) convert them to CRLF when the file is checked out.
- `*.txt eol=lf` tells Git to (1) normalize line endings to LF on checkin and (2) prevent conversion to CRLF when the file is checked out.

Notice that both settings normalize line endings to LF on checkin! This effectively sets the `text` attribute because `text` does the same thing.

---

Since these settings only apply to changes going forward, [additional steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888735/23566) would be needed to update files that are already checked in.

And one more thing... Be careful to set `eol` only on paths matching text files. It enables normalization without any content checks, but binary files should not be normalized. Depending on your paths, you might need to explicitly exclude certain file types:

```
# Disable eol normalization for these types:
*.png -text
*.jpg -text
*.ttf -text
```

Comment: `eol` and `text` still perform binary checks before translating.  That's why the common `* text=auto` is relatively safe.

Comment: `text=auto` tells Git to decide if the file is binary, but `eol` "enables end-of-line normalization without any content checks." - http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @robert Perhaps this has changed, since the documentation now says: "This attribute has effect only if the text attribute is set or unspecified, **or if it is set to auto, the file is detected as text, and it is stored with LF endings in the index**. "