# Can't get Git to work

Tags: git

I have a stupid problem here. When I run the GitHub application it crashes. I've tried to install source tree and play around with it but it crashes too. So I decided to use git shell / bash / cmd. I thought that this would solve the problem, but it didn't.  When I go to my project folder by command `cd /d F:/beabest/Beabest` , everything is just fine. So I tried the `git add .` command and... [image] And it stands there forever. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What editor are you using for your code?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1967370/2627975

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 + Unity :)

Comment: Try changing your line endings in Visual Studio to CRLF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409797.aspx

Comment: I did as you say, But this still appears. I've tried changing the git config core.autocrlf to false too but it didn't help :( I still don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've fixed it. Topic is closed. The solution was simple. Reinstall and take the third option which was is is and is is :)