# why git shows such log in my commit log tree?

Tags: git

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RqIW.png]

As you can see, there is many files remove and add same code line, and it happened a lot.

I wonder why and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This generally happen when git changes the eol (end-of-lines) on all files, because of a [global config like **`core.autocrlf`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309).

Since *all* the lines are modified, git considered they are all "removed" and replaced with new ones.

Try:

```
git config --global core.autocrl false
```

Then clone again your repo, work on it, commit and see if you still list similar logs.