# Editing commits with Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Often after code review, you need to make some minor changes (f.e. changing the comments). And for not to getting back to the commit on your workmachine, edits can be made just from the gerrit.

*For this cases there is an "**Edit**" button, on the commit page.
Or in cases reviewer commented you in a file, there is a "**Fix**" button, on the comment.*

And it works, but the problem is after making edits **sometimes**, the whole edited file is like a new one. I mean each line marked as modified - which I don't like because the whole file histroy dissapears.

**But sometimes it works well** and not rewriting the whole file. I don`t get the difference. Are there any tricks to use Edit functionality, without whole file changing?

Comment: It could be linked to newlines differences between Linux/Mac/Windows. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf

Comment: @EricDuminil that might be true! But the strange thing is that sometimes it works well.

Comment: It depends on your system, your text editor and your local git configuration. So yes, it could work well sometimes