# share Android Studio repository on Windows and Mac

Tags: android, windows, macos, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android development team everyone uses Mac. I want to switch to Windows, so I wonder if there will be incompatibilities in Android Studio projects shared with Git, for example in gradle sections with paths like:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('../the_keystore.jks')
        storePassword '1234'
        keyAlias '1234'
        keyPassword '1234'
    }
}
```

or here:

```
     sourceSets {

        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
        staging {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/staging/res']
        }
        production {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/production/res']
        }
    }
```

and in that case, any possible solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf this is the only issue you could get.

Comment: if you have relative paths, then there are not going to be any problems. So far you showed only relative paths.