# EOL Issue with GIT on .cmd-file on Windows 8.1

Tags: git, batch-file, eol, gitattributes

I have a maven file `mvnw.cmd` in the unstaged files, BUT there are no real modification. It looks to me, it has something to do with *EOL*, because every line has been marked to remove and add.

[image]

I tried already to delete and get out it again from GIT. I tried to stash it, but it still remains as unstaged file.

The `.gitattributes` file:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
*   text=auto

# Make sure that the line ending style ist set to Linux for shell scripts
*.sh        eol=lf


# Make sure that the line ending style ist set to Windows for bat scripts
*.bat       eol=crlf
*.cmd       eol=crlf
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay but what kind of line endings does that file have in the repository?  Use `hexdump` or some editor that will display line endings or hex.  It probably has incorrect line endings in the repository, which needs to be corrected in addition to your `gitattributes`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why, but after update of GIT itself everything is fine.

Git old was `2.9.0`
Git new is `2.15.0`

Issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to how Git converts line endings based on the value of core.autocrlf.
Checkout this question for an explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/4522186