# running lines in my node.js command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

I am new to node.js and Github. I was trying to save some work by using command git add -A and the then I saw these lines below and some many of the lines are just running non-stop. I typed ctrl+c to stop it, but anyone knows what are just happened or what did I do wrong??

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, or anything that you should be terribly worried about. It's just telling you that GitHub uses CRLF as the newline character, and you use LF. The system automatically converts this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how git treats the space character.

Find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967986/2874959

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bcorbella for the answer. Just a small precision to be sure you won't do this as a beginner but never add the `node_modules` into your git project. Create a `.gitignore` file with at least:

```
node_modules
```

Use `npm init`, `npm install <module> --save` to create a `package.json`... then do simply a `npm install` when you are checking your project.

More info in here https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Answer (score 0):

try setting the config `core.eol` to `native` and see if you will get the same error, i see no reason why you should be tracking the `node_modules/` folder.

```
> git config --global core.eol native
```