# Warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Git

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm a bit new to the whole Git process but I'm trying to be better for the sake of my sanity. I'm working on uploading a project from an Ubuntu 18 server to a Bitbucket repository, but when I run the command `git add .` I get a lot of the following warnings:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in public/.htaccess.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

I've gone through but a lot of these refer to Windows machines, I was wondering if there were any suggestions for our Ubuntu 18.04 server so that I can upload the files in this directory?

Comment: What do you mean by 'any suggestions'? Do you want to change to files or are you wondering why they will be replaced by CRLF?

Comment: Well I've tried this method - `git config --global core.autocrlf input` but the warnings still appear.

Comment: Can you try with `git config --global core.safecrlf false` to disable the warning but keep the functionality?

Comment: What does say your `.gitattributes` file (if you have one)?

Comment: At the moment, just these four lines:

Comment: ```* text=auto
*.css linguist-vendored
*.scss linguist-vendored
*.js linguist-vendored
CHANGELOG.md export-ignore```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to me that you have forget create the `commit` previous to `add`