# Handling CRLF on a per project basis in Windows 10 / WSL with git?

Tags: git, windows-10, core.autocrlf

I got the following warning when trying to add my .rdl file to a project in git:

```
leeand00@SOMEWINBOX:/mnt/c/Users/leeand00/source/repos/ProdCompsFromCAPSReport$ git add ./ProdCompsFromCAPSReport/ProdComp_Simph_SSRS2014.rdl
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in ProdCompsFromCAPSReport/ProdComp_Simph_SSRS2014.rdl.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Is there a way to tell `git` that I'd like to handle CRLF for windows instead of for Linux?  AKA using CRLF for my project instead of LF, but only for this project?  Should my `core.autocrlf` setting it go in `.gitattributes` for the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: @LingVu Yes it did; thank you!