# Downloading file with wrong EOL sequences

Tags: batch-file, github, curl

When trying to download a file from my GitHub repository using CURL, it always downloads it correctly with all the content fine, except that it uses LF instead of CRLF, which is what I need for windows. This is used for being able to update a batch file automatically, and it worked fine, except this one specific file. [This is the file that causes problems (GitHub).](https://github.com/L89David/DarviLStuff/blob/master/pbar.bat) When pushing this file from GitHub desktop, I made sure that it was saved as CRLF, but seems like it's somehow ignoring it.

Note: This also happened when using the BITSADMIN tool.

Thank you.

Comment: I would guess you have [autocrlf set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/2378643).  Normally that's ok, but since you want to download the file with crlf from a non-windows machine (namely, github), you want it set to false, then push an update to the file to force the correct versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with changing your usage to include the `-B --Use-ASCII` option like so:

```bat
curl -s -B --Use-ASCII https://raw.githubusercontent.com/L89David/DarviLStuff/master/versions > "!temp!"
```

It does still appear though that in the first script you haven't terminatinated the last line with a `{CR}{LF}`

A small tip with importing variables like this, If you change the stored format to:

```
Set "echoc=59"
Set "pbar=27"
Set "virint=31"
```

And the file type to bat or cmd, You can easily import them by just calling the file once it's downloaded.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding -B --Use-ASCII fixed it completely!