# how to convert a .sh file from CRLF to LF in linux

Tags: linux, azure-devops, sh

I checked in a .sh file in git repo in ADO service but when I'm running a pipeline, the shell script converts to CRLF format so I'm trying to add a task to convert it back to LF format.
Is there a linux command to easily convert it to LF from CRLF? I tried running dos2unix [filename] but no luck.

```
var script: string = path.join(__dirname, 'test.sh');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
//exec(`sudo apt install dos2unix`)
exec(`chmod +x ${script}`)
exec(`dos2unix ${script}`)
```

Comment: `dos2unix` should have worked. Did you get an error?

Comment: `git` "helpfully" converts lf to crlf when you check out on Windows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: @Barmar no error message actually, when I run the command manually it works but doesn't work when I run it through nodejs in ado services pipeline

Comment: @thatotherguy I am uploading the .sh file with LF format to git repo in ADO services but when it's downloaded to an ado agent in the _work folder it is downloaded as CRLF..

Comment: Then the problem must be with how you're trying to run it from node.js. Show your code.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity Does that agent download via git with the `autocrlf` setting enabled? If so, it will add back CRLFs even if it's checked in with LFs

Comment: @Barmar just posted the script

Comment: @thatotherguy hm.. not sure how it's set up.. is there a way to check that easily?

Comment: Are you sure the process running this script has permission to modify the file?

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't this help to give permissions to modify the file? exec(`chmod a+rwx ${script}`)

Comment: Since it needs to be the owner to use `chmod`, you could just use `chmod u+w`

Comment: i had to run exec(`chmod +x ${script}`) first so that the file is executable

Comment: this is the file permission after running the chmod command. rwxr-xr-x