# React adds `\r` to environmental variable when building on windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, environment-variables

My React App (in typescript) uses some environment variables stored in a `.env` file like so:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID=my-project
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN=my-project.firebaseapp.com
```

When building the app with `react-scripts build` ([react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)) on a Mac everything works. Looking at the compiled javascript the environmental variables look like this:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID:"my-project",
```

However when I do the same on a Windows machine there is a `\r` added in the compiled javascript:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID:"my-project\r",
```

which leads to errors.

On both systems all files are of `LF` line ending. And I tried to add this:

```
{
    "files.eol": "\n",
}
```

to the `settings.json` of VSCode on the windows machine, with no effect.

Comment: if you use git to fetch sources, depending on configuration it can replace line endings in sources to \r\n on windows

Comment: But shouldn't then be the line ending on windows CRLF? It is LF

Comment: Build tool splits .env by \n and left \r untouched which ends up in compiled JavaScript

Comment: but shouldn't the .env file then not have LF on windows? How do I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1967370/2079189 (set core.autocrlf to input or false and clone repo again) or run `dos2unix .env` (distributed with git for windows)