# How to fix Git add LF to CRLF warning?

Tags: git

every time I enter the git add command. always appears a warning

> LF will be replaced by CRLF

I have tried to apply the

> git config --global core.autocrlf true

this command works, but every time I try to git add. new projects must always enter the core.autocrlf command.

what I want to ask, is there a way to make this automatically without repeating the core.autocrlf command every time I add a new project

what I want to ask, is there a way to make this automatically without repeating the core.autocrlf command every time I add a new project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `autocrlf` issues were definitely discussed here before. You can find a number of good posts via search here. Please check out  this very detailed post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/1328439. Try the `--system` option if `--global` does not seem to work for you.