# How can I find places where tabs are used in a commit range?

Tags: git, tabs

I am contributing code to an open source project which requires that no tabs exist in source code(only spaces). I am sure I have used tabs accidentally in some places, and want to clean up my code before I submit a patch. How can I find uses of tabs in a commit range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For commits you haven't pushed yet, you can use filter-branch:
See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011985/line-endings-messed-up-in-git-how-to-track-changes-from-another-branch-after-a) for a concrete example

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter '~/Scripts/fix-line-endings.sh' -- --all
```

(that is for all commits, you need to restrict it for a range of commit, see [`git filter-branch` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch))

For future commits, use a **[filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)**

[image]

```
git config --global filter.tabspace.clean 'script_to_clean_tabs_at_eol'
```

Use the '`clean`' step to cleanup tabs.