# Handling line endings for git

Tags: linux, git, unix, newline, line-endings

Here is what I messed up so far,

1. I copied (not cloned) a rails project from windows to linux pc
2. Then created a new branch and made lots of changes
3. At last commited twice whole project and pushed it to a remote repository with windows line endings.

Problem: so my problem is that, since I copied the project from windows to linux, when I run git status whole project shows modified. I don't see the changes I made specifically. Since I committed and pushed whole project, I lost history of files change.

What is needed: So I want to remove my last two commit but I want to keep my changes that I made. Then I want to convert the line endings from windows to unix of whole project so that when I run git status I see only the files that I changed, not whole project. And then I want to commit and push to remote.

It would be nice if there is a solution for this mess.

I am not sure if this will be helpful, I am working on a rails project and my IDE is rubymine.

Comment: When you say that you want to remove you last 2 commits and keep changes, do you mean to keep changes in the repo?

Comment: I want to keep the changes on local

Answer (score 0):

To undo your last two commits run this:

1. `git reset --soft HEAD~2`. This will put the files involved in the commits into your working directory.
2. Run `git status` and they will show as staged changes (ready for commit).
3. Edit your files.
4. Stage and commit your changes. **Important: Don't push**
5. Run `git pull`.
6. Run `git push`

Make sure you commit your changes and do a `git pull` prior to `git push`, otherwise your attempt to push will cause conflict and will be rejected.

Comment: I have been reading about git commands and it seems that I should use git revert instead of git reset since I already pushed my commits.

Comment: @user1670773 My experience of `git revert` is limited so I cannot advise further. All I know is I have used and tested the approach detailed above, but that is not to say it is the 'correct' way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `git filter-branch`.
Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011985).