# Git Diff new line issue

Tags: git, powershell, bamboo

I'm running a git diff command between two commit hashes and i'm exporting it into a .txt file, when I run the diff command from the command line or using a PowerShell script everything is working fine and I see the list of changes between the two commit hashes, but when I take my PowerShell script and run it from Bamboo it will sometimes create a new line in the space between the directories, any suggestions?

For example:
When running from git bash or powershell on my machine:

```
this/is/some thing/weird
xxasasvcvx/ysssdwqtgyyy/yy jjaaaj hjhh/ddddd vv bbb
```

When running from Bamboo:

```
this/is/some 
thing/weird
xxasasvcvx/ysssdwqtgyyy/yy jjaaaj hjhh/ddddd vv bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be due to the trouble with Carriage-Return/Line-Feed between Windows and Linux worlds. You can play with git configuration (see [Removing carriage return from source controled files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018829/608772)).

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true/false/input
git config --global core.safecrlf true/false
```